# How to write a log on an ASP.NET website virtual directory?

Tags: asp.net, iis, log4net, virtual-directory

My website is running as an ASP.NET user in IIS. I've created one virtual directory, 'Logs', which is internally pointing to my shared drive folder which is access by a limited number of users. How can I create a log file on the virtual directory with log4net?

Do I (or can I) provide user credentials when I create the logger or the file?

Comment: What kind of log file? Can't you just point the IIS logs to your virtual directory?

Comment: Do you need to authenticate the user before their session is allowed to create logs? Does the user access the logs directly? Or do you just want to have the current username in the log message, like... `01-01-2011 INFO [anthony.mastrean] Logged on.`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there's [no problem](http://mikeknowles.com/blog/2009/03/27/ConfiguringLog4NetOnAGoDaddyASPNETSite.aspx) writing log files to a virtual directory on your website. You just tell log4net that the path is relative to the current directory by writing the configuration

```
<appender ...>
    <file value="Logs\website.log" />
</appender>
```

Now, if you want to put the current username in the log message, you'll want to investigate log4net [Contexts](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/contexts.html). Stashing the current user in the log4net context

```
log4net.ThreadContext.Properties["user"] = HttpContext.Cache["current-user"];
```

And pulling it out in the Appender [layout](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Layout.PatternLayout.html)

```
<appender ...>
    <layout ...>
        <conversionPattern value="%date %-5level [%property{user}] %message%newline" />
    </layout>
</appender>
```